# SONOS getMediaURI endpoint not called by player

Tags: sonos

I’m developing a custom music service for SONOS in which custom playlists are provided to be played (Spotify alike).

I’ve implemented the required endpoints and I can see while debugging that the GETLASTUPDATE and GETMETADATA endpoints are called and that the information is show in the APP (Playlists list, track list by playlist and artist and album info).

The issue is, When I try to reproduce a complete playlist or a track I get an

> Unable to add songs to Queue

message and no call is done by the app to the API.

What am I missing here?

Below you may find the called the endpoints output.

**Request:**

```
<getMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <id>root</id>
    <index>0</index>
    <count>100</count>
</getMetadata>
```

**Response:**

```
<ns1:getMetadataResponse>
    <ns1:getMetadataResult>
        <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
        <ns1:count>9</ns1:count>
        <ns1:total>9</ns1:total>
        <ns1:mediaCollection>
            <ns1:id>PLAYLIST:10:2</ns1:id>
            <ns1:itemType>playlist</ns1:itemType>
            <ns1:title>Anos 90</ns1:title>
            <ns1:summary>Relembre os hits que marcaram os anos 90. Da música pop ao grunge, esta playlist conta com as presenças de Alanis Morissette, Oasis, Pearl Jam e The Cranberries</ns1:summary>
            <ns1:canPlay>true</ns1:canPlay>             
<ns1:albumArtURI>https://xxx/xxdata/images/playlists/default.jpg</ns1:albumArtURI>
        </ns1:mediaCollection>            
    </ns1:getMetadataResult>
</ns1:getMetadataResponse>
```

**Request:**

```
<getMetadata xmlns="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
    <id>PLAYLIST:10:2</id>
    <index>0</index>
    <count>100</count>
</getMetadata>
```

**Response:**

```
<ns1:getMetadataResponse>
    <ns1:getMetadataResult>
        <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
        <ns1:count>100</ns1:count>
        <ns1:total>338</ns1:total>
        <ns1:mediaMetadata>
            <ns1:id>track:300</ns1:id>
            <ns1:title>Black Hole Sun</ns1:title>
            <ns1:mimeType>audio/mp3</ns1:mimeType>
            <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
            <ns1:trackMetadata>
                <ns1:albumId>album:1390</ns1:albumId>
                <ns1:duration>253970</ns1:duration>
                <ns1:artistId>artist:543</ns1:artistId>
                <ns1:artist>Soundgarden</ns1:artist>
                <ns1:album>Superunknown</ns1:album>
                <ns1:albumArtURI>https://xxxx/musiccover.aspx?pk=xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx</ns1:albumArtURI>
                </ns1:trackMetadata>
            </ns1:mediaMetadata>
        <ns1:mediaMetadata>
            <ns1:id>track:514</ns1:id>
            <ns1:title>Don't Speak</ns1:title>
            <ns1:mimeType>audio/mp3</ns1:mimeType>
            <ns1:itemType>track</ns1:itemType>
            <ns1:trackMetadata>
               <ns1:albumId>album:1128</ns1:albumId>
               <ns1:duration>207196</ns1:duration>
               <ns1:artistId>artist:467</ns1:artistId>
               <ns1:artist>No Doubt</ns1:artist>
               <ns1:album>Tragic Kingdom</ns1:album>
               <ns1:albumArtURI>https://xxxx/musiccover.aspx?pk=xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx</ns1:albumArtURI>
          </ns1:trackMetadata>
      </ns1:mediaMetadata>
    </ns1:getMetadataResult>
</ns1:getMetadataResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that last snippet your actual response? It could be a number of things, but I think the issue may be that your response claims to return 100 results when it only contains 2. To test this, try to use

```
        <ns1:index>0</ns1:index>
        <ns1:count>2</ns1:count>
        <ns1:total>2</ns1:total>
        <ns1:mediaMetadata>. . . <ns1:mediaMetadata>
        <ns1:mediaMetadata>. . . <ns1:mediaMetadata>
```

instead of `count=100, total=338`. The player may be trying to enqueue the rest of the tracks and failing to do so, causing the error.

If you use the `...` menu on the track from the Sonos app's browse, and select "Play Song" the player *should* enqueue only the one track and attempt to play it without dealing with the pagination of the playlist container.

Comment: Hi RJM
Actually I've trimmed the reply, the actual reply object has 100 tracks (of 338).

When I try to play the music at SONOS APP I get a "Unable to add songs do the Queue"
and no call is done to the API